# How to select an option from mat dropdown using Tab key in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am working with a dropdown that has some keys and input fields.

Currently when I select the dropdown and press tab key then it will go to the second dropdown.

The behavior I am expecting is, after selecting the drop-down and I press the tab button it should select the next item in the dropdown.

Below is an image to show the behavior I am expecting

[image]

This is my code

```html
<div class="fromTo">
   <mat-form-field style="width: 30%;">
      <mat-label>From</mat-label>
      <mat-select panelClass="fromSelect" style="margin-top:10% ;">
         <input matInput [(ngModel)]='searchValue' placeholder="Search" style="height: 35px; background-color: #f3f5f8; width: 98%;"/>
         <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="onKeyAgency(searchValue)" class="cursor-pointer" type="button" style="float: right;position: absolute; right: 0;">
            <mat-icon class="search_icon">search</mat-icon>
         </button>
         <button mat-button (click)="showAdd=!showAdd" style="width: 100%;text-align: left;"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>   Add New</button>
         <input matInput [ngClass]="{ 'hide':  showAdd}" [(ngModel)]='newPlace' placeholder="add" style="height: 35px; background-color: #f3f5f8; width: 98%;  position: inherit; "/>
         <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="addPlace(newPlace)" [ngClass]="{ 'hide': showAdd }" class="cursor-pointer" type="button" style="float: right; position: absolute; right: 10%;">
            <mat-icon class="search_icon">done</mat-icon>
         </button>
         <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="newPlace=''" [ngClass]="{ 'hide': showAdd }" class="cursor-pointer" type="button" style="float: right; position: absolute; right: 0;">
            <mat-icon class="search_icon">close</mat-icon>
         </button>
         <mat-option>None</mat-option>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let places of selectedAgencies" [value]="places">{{places}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried by giving `tab index` to each options ?

Comment: i tried adding tab index to options but it is not working

Comment: after adding tab index it gets selected but dropdown got closed

Answer (score 1):

Add a `tabindex` to the options like below in your template -

```
 <div class="fromTo">
       <mat-form-field style="width: 30%;">
             <input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)" />
             <mat-option>None</mat-option>
              <!-- Add table index to matOptions-->
             <mat-option *ngFor="let places of selectedAgencies;let i = index" [value]="places" tabindex="index">{{places}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Then in your component, bind `keydown` event in the input field to a callback in your component. This should avoid the panel getting closed -

```
onKeydown(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 9) {
       event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It contains a coding error `let i = index` -> `tabindex="index"` -> should be `tabindex="{{i}}"`